# Http Post with request content type form not working in Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring-mvc, content-type

code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)//,  headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public ModelAndView create(@RequestBody UserAccountBean account) {
    try{
        accounts.put(account.assignId(), account);
    }catch(RuntimeException ex)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("account/registerError");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("account/userVerification");
}
```

After receiving request, What I got is Http Status code 415:
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().

If I change the code to this:

code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public ModelAndView create(@RequestBody UserAccountBean account) {
    try{
        accounts.put(account.assignId(), account);
    }catch(RuntimeException ex)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("account/registerError");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("account/userVerification");
}
```

I will get  405 Method not allowed. Funny thing is in the allow header of response, it lists GET and POST as allowed methods.

I do have a class that does JOSN mapping:

```
@Component
public class JacksonConversionServiceConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {

private final ConversionService conversionService;

@Autowired
public JacksonConversionServiceConfigurer(ConversionService conversionService) {
    this.conversionService = conversionService;
}

public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
}

public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter) {
        AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter adapter = (AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter) bean;
        HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters = adapter.getMessageConverters();
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = (MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter) converter;
                jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(new ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper(this.conversionService));
            }               
        }
    }
    return bean;
}

}
```

Copied from Spring examples. works great with JSON content-type.

A more general question is how to make spring mvc request handlers work with different request content-types. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Unfortunately `FormHttpMessageConverter` (which is used for `@RequestBody`-annotated parameters when content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) cannot bind target classes (as `@ModelAttribute` can).

Therefore you need `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`. If you don't need to pass different content types to that method you can simply replace the annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@ModelAttribute UserAccountBean account) { ... }
```

Otherwise I guess you can create a separate method form processing form data with the appropriate `headers` attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 
public ModelAndView createFromForm(@ModelAttribute UserAccountBean account) { ... }
```

**EDIT:** Another possible option is to implement your own `HttpMessageConverter` by combining `FormHttpMessageConverter` (to convert input message to the map of parameters) and `WebDataBinder` (to convert map of parameters to the target object).

Comment: BTW, where did you find out that? from any ref docs(if yes, can you please share?) or by try-and-error?

Comment: @Bobo: The fact that `FormHttpMessageConverter` produces `MultiValueMap` can be found in its javadoc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html

Comment: Oops. Did not check the javadoc. Another thing I don't quite get it is why spring framework will not detect that and throw me an error msg at deployment time.

Answer (score 22):

I was having HTTP response code of 415

My problems were resolved when I added Content Type to request header

e.g

"Content-Type: application/json"

Answer (score 4):

At the heart of the problem, we wish to accept both application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-types with the same request handler.

To do this, I use the @RequestBody, which was already working for application/json for me (and generally others from the threads I've found, but there is extra work so application/x-www-form-urlencoded can be used with @RequestBody.

First, create a new HttpMessageConverter capable of changing the request input to an object. I do this by reusing the FormHttpMessageConverter, which is already capable of changing the input to a MultiValueMap. I then change the MultiValueMap to a regular Map, and use Jackson to turn the Map to the desired object.

Here is the code for the HttpMessageConverter:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * <p>Converts HTTP requests with bodies that are application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data to an Object
 * annotated with {@link org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody} in the the handler method.
 *
 * @author Jesse Swidler
 */
public class ObjectHttpMessageConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<Object> {

    private final FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private static final LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> LINKED_MULTI_VALUE_MAP = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    private static final Class<? extends MultiValueMap<String, ?>> LINKED_MULTI_VALUE_MAP_CLASS
            = (Class<? extends MultiValueMap<String, ?>>) LINKED_MULTI_VALUE_MAP.getClass();

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return objectMapper.canSerialize(clazz) && formHttpMessageConverter.canRead(MultiValueMap.class, mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return formHttpMessageConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes();
    }

    @Override
    public Object read(Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        Map<String, String> input = formHttpMessageConverter.read(LINKED_MULTI_VALUE_MAP_CLASS, inputMessage).toSingleValueMap();
        return objectMapper.convertValue(input, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Object o, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("");
    }
}
```

There are many different ways a Spring app might pick up that message converter. For me, it was accomplished in an XML file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="com.terminal.core.services.config.ObjectHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 4 years later this is the only way I've found to generically convert to a @RequestBody object.

Answer (score 2):

Using @ModelAttribute is indeed the preferred way to deal with form parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON worked for me as well, I suppose it makes the JSON interpreter get the data from the body.
I was trying to use PUT though, which is a bit harder.
You can read my post about it [here](http://amirzucker.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/using-rest-in-cloudbees-not-so-simple/).

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

On server side:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/xml", "application/json"})
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        public @ResponseBody
        String methodName(@RequestBody EntityClassName entity) {
```

On client side:

```
String json = new JSONStringer().object()
                        .key("key").value("value")
                        .endObject()
                        .toString();
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
request.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for convert html form to json .

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(form) {
                        var array = $(form).serializeArray();
                        var json = {};

                        $.each(array, function() {
                            json[this.name] = this.value || '';
                        });

                        return json;
                    }
```

and use single quotations was wrong . I changed ' ' to " " and problem solved.