# Spring @MVC and the @RequestBody annotation with x-www-form-urlencoded data?

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying to figure out why I can't receive a request from a jQuery.ajax call when then Spring `@Controller` handler method includes a `@RequestBody` annotation. Consider the following:

**HTML/JavaScript**:

```
<form id="foo" action="/baz">
  <input name="bar">
</form>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var $fooForm = $('#foo');

    $fooForm.on('submit', function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url: $fooForm.action,
        data: $fooForm.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Java**:

```
@RequestMapping(
  value = "/baz",
  method = RequestMethod.POST,
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
  produces = MediatType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public @ResponseBody SearchResults[] jqueryPostHandler(
  @RequestBody FormDataObject formData)
{
  return this.searchService.find(formData);
}
```

The above will fail with the `@RequestBody` annotation present and return a 415 error (no exception will be generated). But if the `@RequestBody` annotation is removed (i.e. the parameter signature is just `FormDataObject formData`) then the method will be called and JSON will be returned to the JavaScript.

Why is this the case? A `POST` request includes the data in the body of the request. Shouldn't the annotation process such a request?

I realize that I could change the content type sent by the JavaScript to `application/json` and the `consumes` property to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to make the annotation work correctly. But why doesn't it work with a normal form request?

**Note**: I am using Spring 3.1.4.

Comment: http://matthewsalvatore.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/spring-framework-working-with-x-www.html

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried turning up logging on 'org.springframework.web' to find out the reason for the returned status code? There should be an exception raised and logged before it's translated to a 415.

Also if sending form data, why not just leave out the @RequestBody. You'll then be use data binding (i.e. @ModelAttribute) that will apply Servlet request parameters to object fields. This is preferable to using the FormHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: Turning up logging shows that with the `@RequestBody` annotation in place it _does_ map to the right method, but it throws "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported".

Comment: From my limited understanding, the annotation `@RequestBody` implies that the data to be processed will be in the body of the request. This informs the compiler _and_ the person reading the code. So, leaving it makes for ambiguous code. That's why I want to know why this is failing.

Answer (score 6):

As the [Spring Docs of @RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) says, the request body would be converted to your object by `HttpMessageConverter`.

There are 4 default HttpMessageConverters:

- [ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.html): converts byte arrays.
- [StringHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html): converts strings.
- [FormHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html): converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.
- [SourceHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/SourceHttpMessageConverter.html): converts
  to/from a javax.xml.transform.Source.

To convert the url encoded form, which is ajax.serialize() create, it's the job of `FormHttpMessageConverter`. Since you have a `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` exception, I guess that you didn't configure `FormHttpMessageConverter`. Check your spring configuration file, here is an example :

```
< bean class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" >
   < property name= "messageConverters" >
         < list>
             < ref bean= "mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
             < ref bean= "stringHttpMessageConverter" /> 
             <!-- Do you have this converter ? -->
             < ref bean= "formHttpMessageConverter" />
         </ list>
    </ property>
</ bean>
```

Comment: The above did not work for me, even if I added all converters. I had to use the custom converter at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31083802/471213 to make it work

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ is your problem the same as this question? my answer is for this question, and if yours is different, or maybe your should ask a new question to explain more details.

Comment: Not the same exact problem: I have error 406 when submitting form and success when submitting JSON. However, before I debugged with code from Spring, I did not understand that the request entity **must** someway implement `MultiValueMap` in order to work with `FormHttpMessageConverter`. So *now* I am starting to think that either the OP's `FormDataObject` implements that interface or else I am having the same problem as the OP but adding that converter doesn't work. And by the way I am using Spring 4.2

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I suggest you to ask a new question for your problem, in this comment, not enough information is provided.

Comment: Using `FormHttpMessageConverter` means I cannot bind the form to a custom Object? It will always convert to MultiValueMap?

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes, it should be that case. But you can convert the MultiValueMap to Object by yourself.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that when we use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this
we must remove the **@RequestBody** annotation.

Then try the following:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/baz",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        produces = MediatType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public @ResponseBody SearchResults[] jqueryPostHandler(
        FormDataObject formData)
{
    return this.searchService.find(formData);
}
```

Note that removed the annotation **@RequestBody**

*answer*: [Http Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin/38252762#38252762)