# Spring: Why can't i get POST parameters with @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, post

My JSP

```
<form method="POST" action="/searchClips">
   <input type="text" name="streamer">
   <input type="checkbox" name="player" value="hello">Hello
   <input class="searchButton" type="image" src="/static/images/buttons/button_search.png"
                       alt="Search">
</form>
```

My Servlet

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/searchClips"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String searchClips(@RequestBody Clip clip) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        System.out.println(clip);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

When I click on the search button, which does a POST to /searchClips, I'm getting a 415 response code:

```
Problem accessing /views/searchClips. Reason:

    Unsupported Media Type
```

Here's my log:

```
DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/searchClips]
RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /searchClips
RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.projectName.controllers.HomeController.searchClips(com.projectName.models.Clip)]
DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'homeController'
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.projectName.controllers.HomeController.searchClips(com.projectName.models.Clip)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported
DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

[image]

Comment: How is the form actually being transmitted to the server? (Check the "network" panel of your browser's debugger if you're not sure.) Is there a reason you're specifying a `consumes` type instead of letting Spring automagic it?

Comment: i thought putting the consumes would handle the org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported but it didn't

Comment: i've added what's being transmitted, there are some additional fields in there that i didn't put in my example

Comment: Okay, so you're getting the `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` both with and without the `consumes`? Are you sure that you rebuilt and redeployed your code and you're not running the old version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Http Post with request content type form not working in Spring MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339207/http-post-with-request-content-type-form-not-working-in-spring-mvc-3)

Comment: yes, i just double checked again

Comment: thank you so much, changing RequestBody to ModelAttribute did the trick!