# Request method 'POST' not supported and amazon elastic beantalk

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to use post method in my controller with java annotation ( version 4.2.1)and success in my local tomcat, but when I moved to amazon beantalk I get the follow error:

**log:**

```
28-Sep-2015 10:34:11.339 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported
28-Sep-2015 10:34:11.340 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
28-Sep-2015 10:34:11.994 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported
28-Sep-2015 10:34:11.995 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
28-Sep-2015 10:34:15.915 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported
28-Sep-2015 10:34:15.915 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
28-Sep-2015 10:34:16.938 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported
28-Sep-2015 10:34:16.938 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException Handler execution resulted in exception: **Request method 'POST' not supported**
28-Sep-2015 10:34:17.660 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported
```

**appConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"service","controller"})
public class AppConfig {

public AppConfig(){

        System.out.println("AppConfig!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

    @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

      /**
       * Actor system singleton for this application.
       */
      @Bean (name="ActorSystem")
      public ActorSystem actorSystem() {
          System.out.println("system issssssssssssssssssssssssss" );
          try {
              ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("AkkaJavaSpring");
              System.out.println("system issssssssssssssssssssssssss2222222222" );

                // initialize the application context in the Akka Spring Extension
                SpringExtProvider.get(system).initialize(applicationContext);
                return system;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ActorSystem initialized exception: " + e);
        }

          System.err.println("no exception!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" );
        return null;
      }
```

**AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer**:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("getRootConfigClasses!!!!!!!!!!!!!! succed");
        return new Class<?>[] {
            WebConfig.class,
            AppConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        System.out.println("filter !!!!!!!!!!!!!! succed");
        return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() };
    }

}
```

**webConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
      public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {

//      configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(
//              MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
                favorParameter(true).
                parameterName("mediaType").
                ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
                useJaf(false).
                defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
                mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

      }

    @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");

      }
```

**controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/mail")
public class SendMailController {


    //Dispatcher dispatcher; 

    //@Autowired
    public SendMailController(){
        //this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        System.out.println("SendMailController has been loaded!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }



    @RequestMapping(produces = "application/json" ,method=RequestMethod.POST )

    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> sendMail(@RequestBody MailRequest mailRequest){

        System.out.println("MailRequest 2 mailRequest!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " );

    //  dispatcher.SendMail(new MailRequestEvent(mailRequest));
        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

please i relly need help here

Comment: Perhaps this link can help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339207/http-post-with-request-content-type-form-not-working-in-spring-mvc-3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my URL there is a different between the URL to tomcat and the URL
To elastic the deferent is that to elastic you don't include the project name in the URL and in tomcat you have to include the project name

Thanks