# /graphql POST method not allowed in springboot graphql app deployed on AWS lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, graphql

i have spring boot application which use graphql-java-kickstart
/
graphql-spring-boot,

basically i am creating graphQL server using spring boot app
which i am deploying on AWS lambda

so on local if run spring-boot app then it works fine

but on AWS Lambda getting error **Request method 'POST' not supported**

Comment: add some code with properties file and API for which it shows this error.

Comment: @Hemant
whenever you create a spring boot application using graphql-spring-boot by graphql-java-kickstart 
then it by default provide you POST endpoint /graphql which is basically sit behind tomcat server
but in case when we need to deploy the same on AWS lambda we need to exclude tomcat server and include aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2
and now i am getting 405 when try to hit /graphql

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for might have already been answered, have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339207/http-post-with-request-content-type-form-not-working-in-spring-mvc-3) It seems to approach the same problem you are having

Comment: @TiagoCarneiro 
Thanks for link
But it is different 
My point is just that when things work automatically on ECS with graphql-spring-boot
then it should work in same way on lambda as well and i am getting 405 so endpoint is getting registered automagically but with wrong verb(GET)

Comment: @GauravTanwar I'm also experiencing the same issue, Do you have any resolution for this issue, please post